# Is SSL key generation client-side, server-side, or both?

Tags: cryptography, tls, key-management

Who generates the session keys for a SSL symmetric encryption? Is it the client for both client and server where client generates part of it while the server generates the other part?

Answer (score 12):

In SSL protocol handshake both sides generate the same encryption key which is then used for the session. It is done following this procedure, in general:

1. Client & server generate each a random value and send to each other
2. Server sends the public key to the client
3. The client generates a value called "pre-master secret" using both random values, and encrypts it using server's key, then sends it to the server
4. Now both client and server have each other's random values and "pre-master secret", so basing on this information they can both generate the same session key and start using it in encrypting the following messages.

See [detailed protocol description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785811%28WS.10%29.aspx) for [more in-depth explanation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_intro.html).

Comment: is this something like diffie hellman key exchange protocol ?

Comment: DH can be used as key exchange protocol, yes. Usually DH is used when there's no certificates in play and RSA if there are certificates. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_intro.html

Comment: This is not accurate. The random values + premastersecret are never sent in the clear; the random value that the client generates gets encrypted using the server's public key. Most of the rest is correct, though I'm hoping @Thomas will clarify some of the subtler details...

Comment: @AviD: sorry, I was away for a couple of weeks. In SSL, both client and server send random blurbs in the clear. They also run a key exchange protocol which results in a premaster secret (with RSA, the client chooses the premaster and encrypts it with the server public key; but they can also use Diffie-Hellman). The actual encryption and MAC keys are derived from the premaster _and_ the client and server randoms.

Comment: @StasM: DH without certificate is vulnerable to active MITM attack. You still need a certificate to prove your identity in DH.

Comment: Sorry, but how exactly the client received server's pre-master-secret?